docker container can't resolve hostnames defined in dns-server container
dns-server container
version: "3"
services:
  dns-server:
    container_name: dns-server
    hostname: dns-server
    image: technitium/dns-server:latest
    # For DHCP deployments, use "host" network mode and remove all the port mappings, including the ports array by commenting them
    # network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "5380:5380/tcp" #DNS web console (HTTP)
      - "53443:53443/tcp" #DNS web console (HTTPS)
      - "53:53/udp" #DNS service
      - "53:53/tcp" #DNS service
      # - "853:853/udp" #DNS-over-QUIC service
      # - "853:853/tcp" #DNS-over-TLS service
      # - "443:443/udp" #DNS-over-HTTPS service (HTTP/3)
      # - "443:443/tcp" #DNS-over-HTTPS service (HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2)
      # - "80:80/tcp" #DNS-over-HTTP service (use with reverse proxy or certbot certificate renewal)
      # - "8053:8053/tcp" #DNS-over-HTTP service (use with reverse proxy)
      # - "67:67/udp" #DHCP service
    environment:
      - DNS_SERVER_DOMAIN=dns-server #The primary domain name used by this DNS Server to identify itself.
      - DNS_SERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password #DNS web console admin user password.
      # - DNS_SERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD_FILE=password.txt #The path to a file that contains a plain text password for the DNS web console admin user.
      # - DNS_SERVER_PREFER_IPV6=false #DNS Server will use IPv6 for querying whenever possible with this option enabled.
      - DNS_SERVER_WEB_SERVICE_HTTP_PORT=5380 #The TCP port number for the DNS web console over HTTP protocol.
      - DNS_SERVER_WEB_SERVICE_HTTPS_PORT=53443 #The TCP port number for the DNS web console over HTTPS protocol.
      - DNS_SERVER_WEB_SERVICE_ENABLE_HTTPS=true #Enables HTTPS for the DNS web console.
      - DNS_SERVER_WEB_SERVICE_USE_SELF_SIGNED_CERT=false #Enables self signed TLS certificate for the DNS web console.
      # - DNS_SERVER_OPTIONAL_PROTOCOL_DNS_OVER_HTTP=false #Enables DNS server optional protocol DNS-over-HTTP on TCP port 8053 to be used with a TLS terminating reverse proxy like nginx.
      # - DNS_SERVER_RECURSION=AllowOnlyForPrivateNetworks #Recursion options: Allow, Deny, AllowOnlyForPrivateNetworks, UseSpecifiedNetworks.
      # - DNS_SERVER_RECURSION_DENIED_NETWORKS=1.1.1.0/24 #Comma separated list of IP addresses or network addresses to deny recursion. Valid only for `UseSpecifiedNetworks` recursion option.
      # - DNS_SERVER_RECURSION_ALLOWED_NETWORKS=127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.0/24 #Comma separated list of IP addresses or network addresses to allow recursion. Valid only for `UseSpecifiedNetworks` recursion option.
      - DNS_SERVER_ENABLE_BLOCKING=false #Sets the DNS server to block domain names using Blocked Zone and Block List Zone.
      # - DNS_SERVER_ALLOW_TXT_BLOCKING_REPORT=false #Specifies if the DNS Server should respond with TXT records containing a blocked domain report for TXT type requests.
      # - DNS_SERVER_BLOCK_LIST_URLS= #A comma separated list of block list URLs.
      - DNS_SERVER_FORWARDERS=1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8 #Comma separated list of forwarder addresses.
      # - DNS_SERVER_FORWARDER_PROTOCOL=Tcp #Forwarder protocol options: Udp, Tcp, Tls, Https, HttpsJson.
      - DNS_SERVER_LOG_USING_LOCAL_TIME=true #Enable this option to use local time instead of UTC for logging.
    volumes:
      - config:/etc/dns
    networks:
      - dns-network
    restart: unless-stopped
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=1024 65000

volumes:
    config:

networks:
  dns-network:
    name: dns-network
    driver: bridge

gitea container
version: "3"

networks:
  gitea-network:
    name: dns-network
    external: true

services:
  server:
    image: gitea/gitea:1.17.3
    container_name: gitea
    environment:
      - USER_UID=1000
      - USER_GID=1000
      - GITEA__database__DB_TYPE=mysql
      - GITEA__database__HOST=db:3306
      - GITEA__database__NAME=gitea
      - GITEA__database__USER=gitea
      - GITEA__database__PASSWD=gitea
    restart: always
    networks:
      - gitea-network
    volumes:
      - ./gitea:/data
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "222:22"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=gitea
      - MYSQL_USER=gitea
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=gitea
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=gitea
    networks:
      - gitea-network
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

jenkins container
version: '3'

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    container_name: jenkins
    user: root
    ports:
      - "35000:8080"
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /home/david/docker-jenkins/run.sh:/var/jenkins_home/run.sh
      - /home/david/docker-jenkins/ssh-keys:/var/jenkins_home/.ssh
    networks:
      - jenkins-network

networks:
  jenkins-network:
    name: dns-network
    external: true

volumes:
  jenkins_home:

I've tried

dns: dns-server
dns: 127.0.0.1
dns: 192.168.2.170
dns: 172.21.0.2 (dns-server container IP)

followed by sudo docker compose down && sudo docker compose up -d
But it never resolves jenkins.webdev or gitea.webdev to 192.168.2.170 like set up in dns-server
dns-server is working fine.



This is all inside a Ubuntu VM, my Windows Host machine has 192.168.2.170 as primary DNS and resolves jenkins.webdev and gitea.webdev just fine.
Edit: Updated my docker-compose.yml files to reflect current state, I've tried stopping all containers and then:

Create a network inside the dns-server compose file

networks:
  dns-network:
    name: dns-network
    driver: bridge


Adding that network to jenkins and gitea composer files

networks:
  gitea-network:
    name: dns-network
    external: true

services:
  server:
     networks:
      - gitea-network
  dns: dns-server

still doesn't work, inside gitea container I can ping dns-server and the ip shown is correct one, but if I ping webdev, gitea.webdev or jenkins.webdev I get ping: bad address
I can ping jenkins or gitea, and I see the local IPs but jenkins.webdev and gitea.webdev which point to my host IP 192.168.2.170 as defined in dns-server are bad address, and if I try using jenkins or gitea I get Delivery: Post "https://jenkins/gitea-webhook/post": dial tcp 172.20.0.5:443: connect: connection refused
